# Unauthorized errors in the mongoDB logs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Did the mongoAuth for the both Primary & secodary replica sets but getting the below error in the mongoDB logs

2020-07-06T10:50:14.404+0000 I ACCESS   [conn10079868] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { endSessions: [ { id: UUID("e03ba751-1292-479b-aa91-   f57251a3c59b") } ], $db: "admin" }

Have not observed any functionality impact due to these logs but may I know the reason for getting these logs and how to avoid these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue arose in the monitoring module in the mongoDB agent because it creates both the unauthed and authed client connections for all new hosts, independent of if the host requires authentication. Due to this, the failure messages are showing up in the mongoDB audit logs.

This got fixed in the mongoDB 4.5.1 version.
For more details:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-50211
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-49165

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the roles specified on the db user, the permission grant on the user might be the issue for this warning log.

Comment: I created the role "{ role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }" for the admin user as per the mongo documentation. Am I missed anything here ?

Comment: Are you using localdb or atlas?

Comment: I am using localdb only. I updated the "role : root" as well but still seeing the same issue. It looks like admin does n't have enough roles to execute the "endSessions"

Comment: You can try editing user role as dbAdmin to avoid the error. You can refer this link:   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-administration-roles